# Pandas group by and choose all rows except last one in group

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas df as follows:

```
MATERIAL    DATE         HIGH    LOW
AAA       2022-01-01     10      0
AAA       2022-01-02     0       0
AAA       2022-01-03     5       2
BBB       2022-01-01     0       0
BBB       2022-01-02     10      5
BBB       2022-01-03     8       4
```

I want to `groupby` `MATERIAL` and `sort_values` by `DATE`
and choose all rows except last one in the group.
The resulting result should be:

```
MATERIAL    DATE         HIGH    LOW
AAA       2022-01-01     10      0
AAA       2022-01-02     0       0
BBB       2022-01-01     0       0
BBB       2022-01-02     10      5
```

I have tried `df.sort_values('DATE').groupby('MATERIAL').head(-1)` but this results in an empty df.
The `DATE` is a `pd.datetime` object.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is to sort by dates first, then group and take every row except the last one using indexing:

```
>>> df.sort_values("DATE").groupby("MATERIAL").apply(lambda group_df: group_df.iloc[:-1])
           MATERIAL        DATE  HIGH  LOW
MATERIAL                                  
AAA      0      AAA  2022-01-01    10    0
         1      AAA  2022-01-02     0    0
BBB      3      BBB  2022-01-01     0    0
         4      BBB  2022-01-02    10    5
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with `keep='last'` for all values without last:

```
df = df.sort_values(['MATERIAL','DATE'])
df = df[df['MATERIAL'].duplicated(keep='last')]
print (df)
  MATERIAL        DATE  HIGH  LOW
0      AAA  2022-01-01    10    0
1      AAA  2022-01-02     0    0
3      BBB  2022-01-01     0    0
4      BBB  2022-01-02    10    5
```

With groupby solution is possible by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with descending count and filter all rows without `0`:

```
df = df.sort_values(['MATERIAL','DATE'])
df = df[df.groupby('MATERIAL').cumcount(ascending=False).ne(0)]
print (df)
  MATERIAL        DATE  HIGH  LOW
0      AAA  2022-01-01    10    0
1      AAA  2022-01-02     0    0
3      BBB  2022-01-01     0    0
4      BBB  2022-01-02    10    5
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
(df.groupby('MATERIAL', as_index=False, group_keys=False)
   .apply(lambda d: d.iloc[:len(d)-1])
)
```

output:

```
  MATERIAL        DATE  HIGH  LOW
0      AAA  2022-01-01    10    0
1      AAA  2022-01-02     0    0
3      BBB  2022-01-01     0    0
4      BBB  2022-01-02    10    5
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be using `groupby+transform` with `nth` as -1, and compare this with DATE column and only select rows which doesnot match this:

---

```
df = df.sort_values(['MATERIAL','DATE'])
c = df['DATE'].ne(df.groupby("MATERIAL")['DATE'].transform('nth',-1))
out = df[c].copy()
```

---

```
print(out)

  MATERIAL        DATE  HIGH  LOW
0      AAA  2022-01-01    10    0
1      AAA  2022-01-02     0    0
3      BBB  2022-01-01     0    0
4      BBB  2022-01-02    10    5
```

Side note: Since you have a date column, you can also use transform with `max` or `last` but that would only limit you to the last row as opposed to the second last row for example for which you might need `nth` as shown above:

```
c = df['DATE'].ne(df.groupby("MATERIAL")['DATE'].transform('max'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.loc[df1.sort_values(['MATERIAL','DATE'])\
    .duplicated(subset='MATERIAL',keep='last')]\
    .pipe(print)

  MATERIAL        DATE  HIGH  LOW
0      AAA  2022-01-01    10    0
1      AAA  2022-01-02     0    0
3      BBB  2022-01-01     0    0
4      BBB  2022-01-02    10    5
```